# Understand what is KBuild

Tags: compilation, linux-kernel

I'm a newbie to Linux kernel.

I'm trying to understand the idea, high level what is [kbuild](http://svn.netlabs.org/kbuild/).

When I compile kernel I call *make*, which is on Linux machine will GNU make.

So what is KBuild? Is it a set of makefiles which are used by including in kernel makefiles? 
Where [kmk](http://svn.netlabs.org/kbuild/wiki/kmk%20Quick%20Reference) is used?

Reference will be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The links you have mentioned have nothing to do with the Linux kernel. kbuild is an assortment of scripts that are **built-in** inside the kernel's sources, and the kernel build process does not depend on anything named kmk. The kernel build system depends only on the standard GNU make, and it takes care of compiling its own helper programs, most of which are located under `scripts/` directory.

Under the source tree, there is a directory  [Documentation/kbuild](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/) – it contains some documentation on using the kernel's build system.