# C program can't find some included header files though they exist

Tags: c, linux, gcc, header-files

I'm trying to compile a program with this gcc command:

```
gcc -c -fomit-frame-pointer -O2 sth.c
```

These header files are included:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>    //line 1
#include <linux/module.h>    //line 2
#include <sys/syscall.h>     //line 3
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>   //line 4
#include <linux/types.h>     //line 5
#include <linux/dirent.h>    //line 6
#include <asm/unistd.h>      //line 7
```

I get `"no such file or directory"` error for line 2,4 and 6 though they are located in `/usr/src/kernels/3.10.14-100.fc18.x86_64/include/linux/` just as the other 4.

I've compiled some other programs whitch include kernel header files on this system before (using Makefiles) (fedora 18) before and I'm sure for example it didn't get such error for `dirent.h` or `proc_fs.h`. 
I think maybe I should use some other options with gcc that maybe was considered in those Makefiles!

`kernel-headerfiles` and `kernel-devel` package of the same version of my running kernel is installed.

Comment: It's nice of you to tell us the problematic line numbers, but how are we supposed to know what these lines contain?

Comment: Please Stop Writing Like This. It's horrible to read.

Comment: @ ugoren @ Smax Smaxović : Sorry.I hope now it's more readble.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Having trouble compiling C code on ubuntu. (#include errors)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19310541/having-trouble-compiling-c-code-on-ubuntu-include-errors)

Answer (score 1):

The userspace kernel headers are located in `/usr/include/linux`, not in `/usr/src/...`. The latter path contains headers intended for kernel modules, not userspace programs.

If the program is question is actually a kernel module, then you need to use KBuild in order to compile it, since kernel modules need a special build environment. See: [Understand what is KBuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016678/understand-what-is-kbuild/8018787#8018787)

Also take a look at:

```
/usr/src/linux/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt
```

Comment: @ Nikos C.:This program is a kernel module. Sorry that I didn't mention, I've not noticed this.

Comment: @Mjina Kernel modules can't be compiled like normal programs. Use KBuild to get a kernel build environment. I updated the answer.